# Convert Static PHP/MYSQL Query to Dynamic One Using Ajax/jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, wordpress

I have a counter that takes a sum from a database column and updates on every page load. I need to convert this to a live counter that updates without page load.

It's on a WordPress site, and I'm hoping not to have to create a separate page outside of WP in order to send the JSON array.

1) Is there any way to use the current page to submit/receive the POST data?
2) What's the best process for converting a simple 'SELECT * FROM' to something dynamic. Is ajax/jQuery the right choice?

Thanks!

Comment: "Is ajax/jQuery the right choice?" Yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to update the value every 5 seconds

```
window.setInterval(function(){
        $.getJSON('/getLatestCount.php', function(data) {
            $('#id_of_element_where_it_needs_to_be_put').html(data.count);
        });
}, 5000);
```

if the query needs to have the contents of a form, use:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
        $.getJSON('/getLatestCount.php', $("#my_form_id").serialize(), function(data) {
            $('#id_of_element_where_it_needs_to_be_put').html(data.count);
        });
}, 5000);
```

This doesn't use POST but GET but that shouldn't be a problem i think. In the http file use `$_GET['my_field_name']` to access the form values.

You can output the json data in php through `echo json_encode()`

Looking at your question and that you're asking something for wordpress i'm not sure you know how to do this all though so i won't start going into depts about polling and websocket. This is the easiest way to do it.